# SVN Precommit hook: current working directory of client machine

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, pre-commit-hook

I am trying to setup a pre-commit hook in the SVN server side. The pre-commit script is working fine. But I want to run this precommit hook only for particular directory in the SVN Repo but not for all the folders. please help :)

ex: I would like to run the pre-commit hook **ONLY for "trunk\scripts"** folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svnlook` is your best friend for most tasks of hooks.

In your case you have to look at [`svnlook dirs-changed`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnlook.c.dirs-changed.html), which output list oif all directories, affected by transaction and plain `| grep` will check presence of directory-of-interest it it